# What is the maximum filename length in Windows 10? Java would try / catch would trough exeption?

Tags: java, windows, file, filenames

In old versions of windows I know the max is something around 250 characters for files or folders approximately, does anyone know if they changed it in Windows 10 ?

**EDIT:**

I'm doing some Java code around given API to extract some content of a application, will be few thousand files, and I'm a bit concern about what could happen as I don't know what the file name and path will look like so I will try to prevent those errors maybe maybe changing the name in Java before save (but ideal keep the original name),

so do you know if there would be some exemption been thrown ? `File file = new File(jsonFile);` ?  thank I could potentially treat in the catch

Comment: It use to be 256 bytes. _MAX_PATH

Comment: When you say "filename length," do you really mean **name**, or **path**?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  at the moment i'm more interested in the file name because, however the the length of the path is a helpful information to have

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really mean file **name**, I believe the limit is still "commonly" 255 characters, see the third quoted paragraph (*"The Windows API has many..."*) below.

If you mean file **path**: You can enable the "Win32 long paths" option. From [this Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation):

> **Maximum Path Length Limitation**
>
> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is **MAX_PATH**, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "`D:\some 256-character path string<NUL>`" where "`<NUL>`" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)
>
> > Note
> >
> > File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "`/`" to "`\`" as part of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the "`\\?\`" prefix as detailed in the following sections.
>
> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an extended-length path, use the "`\\?\`" prefix. For example, "`\\?\D:\very long path`".
>
> > Note
> >
> > The maximum path of 32,767 characters is approximate, because the "`\\?\`" prefix may be expanded to a longer string by the system at run time, and this expansion applies to the total length.
>
> The "`\\?\`" prefix can also be used with paths constructed according to the universal naming convention (UNC). To specify such a path using UNC, use the "`\\?\UNC\`" prefix. For example, "`\\?\UNC\server\share`", where "server" is the name of the computer and "share" is the name of the shared folder. These prefixes are not used as part of the path itself. They indicate that the path should be passed to the system with minimal modification, which means that you cannot use forward slashes to represent path separators, or a period to represent the current directory, or double dots to represent the parent directory. Because you cannot use the "`\\?\`" prefix with a relative path, relative paths are always limited to a total of **MAX_PATH** characters.
>
> There is no need to perform any Unicode normalization on path and file name strings for use by the Windows file I/O API functions because the file system treats path and file names as an opaque sequence of **WCHAR**s. Any normalization that your application requires should be performed with this in mind, external of any calls to related Windows file I/O API functions.
>
> When using an API to create a directory, the specified path cannot be so long that you cannot append an 8.3 file name (that is, the directory name cannot exceed **MAX_PATH** minus 12).
>
> The shell and the file system have different requirements. It is possible to create a path with the Windows API that the shell user interface is not able to interpret properly.
>
> **Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later**
>
> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, **MAX_PATH** limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.
>
> To enable the new long path behavior, both of the following conditions must be met:
>
> - The registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` `LongPathsEnabled` (Type: REG_DWORD) must exist and be set to 1. The key's value will be cached by the system (per process) after the first call to an affected Win32 file or directory function (see below for the list of functions). The registry key will not be reloaded during the lifetime of the process. In order for all apps on the system to recognize the value of the key, a reboot might be required because some processes may have started before the key was set.
>
> > Note
> >
> > This registry key can also be controlled via Group Policy at Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem > Enable NTFS long paths.
>
> - The application manifest must also include the longPathAware element.
>
>   ```
>   <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
>       <windowsSettings xmlns:ws2="https://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">
>           <ws2:longPathAware>true</ws2:longPathAware>
>       </windowsSettings>
>   </application>
>   ```
>
> These are the directory management functions that no longer have **MAX_PATH** restrictions if you opt-in to long path behavior: CreateDirectoryW, CreateDirectoryExW GetCurrentDirectoryW RemoveDirectoryW SetCurrentDirectoryW.
>
> These are the file management functions that no longer have **MAX_PATH** restrictions if you opt-in to long path behavior: CopyFileW, CopyFile2, CopyFileExW, CreateFileW, CreateFile2, CreateHardLinkW, CreateSymbolicLinkW, DeleteFileW, FindFirstFileW, FindFirstFileExW, FindNextFileW, GetFileAttributesW, GetFileAttributesExW, SetFileAttributesW, GetFullPathNameW, GetLongPathNameW, MoveFileW, MoveFileExW, MoveFileWithProgressW, ReplaceFileW, SearchPathW, FindFirstFileNameW, FindNextFileNameW, FindFirstStreamW, FindNextStreamW, GetCompressedFileSizeW, GetFinalPathNameByHandleW.

Note that while that article says the Group Policy editor's setting is "Enable NTFS long paths", that's no longer the case; it's "Enable Win32 long paths" now:

[image]

Comment: awesome ! do you know if is the same for Windows Server ?

Comment: @Philippe - See the updated answer for more details. I don't know about Windows Server; [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server) the latest version of Windows Server is Windows Server, version 1903 (10.0.18362), which would suggest that it's Windows 10 and after the relevant minimum version for support.

Comment: Guys thank you so much for the answers 

Comment: For a reference on the maximum length of path components, see [\[MS-FSCC\] 2.1.5 Pathname](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-fscc/ffb795f3-027d-4a3c-997d-3085f2332f6f). The last point states that "[e]ach pathname component MUST be no more than 255 characters in length". The NT driver API has `MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH` (256) in "km/wdm.h". In the Windows API, the limit that I'm familiar with is `MAX_PATH` (260), from `cFileName` (not a path) in [`WIN32_FIND_DATAW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-win32_find_dataw).

Answer (score 3):

The maximum length of a path component (directory or file name) is usually 255 but might be shorter on some file systems on external storage (CD-ROM, FAT-16 floppy etc.). The only way to know for sure is to call [`GetVolumeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa). This function reports the maximum component as a DWORD but Windows is currently limited to 255.

The maximum length of a complete path varies:

The limit people often talk about is 260 which comes from the `MAX_PATH` constant. This is the absolute limit on Windows 95/98/ME.

On [Windows NT based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases) systems this limit can be [bypassed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) when calling the Unicode version of the low-level file system functions in kernel32 by using a special prefix. Paths prefixed with `\\?\` are passed directly to the NT API. Relative paths are not supported when you do this. These paths are limited to around 32.000 characters and this limit comes from the string format used in the Windows kernel.

Even though this method has been supported for 25 years, most of Windows is still limited to `MAX_PATH`. The shell/Explorer has this limit in various places and `CreateProcess` also has this limit.

Windows 10 added support for paths longer than `MAX_PATH` without the special prefix. This support is only activated if the application has opted in to this behavior in their manifest **and** the "Enable Win32 long paths" [policy](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing) has been enabled on the system.

Most of the `MAX_PATH` limits in the shell/Explorer have been removed in Windows 10.

Comment: Regarding "in theory be more than 255", per [MS-FSCC], a specification for file-system control codes and data structures -- a path component must not exceed 255 characters. Per NT, the limit is `MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH` (256). In practice it's 255 because this is a maximum buffer size, which leaves space for an optional null. For example, `FindFirstFileW` calls `NtQueryDirectoryFile[Ex]`. The latter fails with `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` if its `FileName` parameter exceeds 255 characters. This isn't file-system dependent, i.e. it fails without sending the request to the file system.

Comment: Note that, even if long paths are enabled in Windows 10, `CreateProcessW` fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` if the path length of the implicitly inherited current directory (i.e. `lpCurrentDirectory` is `NULL`) exceeds `MAX_PATH - 2` (258). The classic current-directory limit is 258 characters in order to leave space for a trailing backslash and a terminating null. Apparently it assumes the target executable doesn't support long paths, instead of checking its manifest. This is a non-obvious error since none of the parameters passed to `CreateProcessW` is obviously invalid.

Comment: @ErykSun Thanks for the excellent corrections.